# Consulta en sql server no devuelve resultado deseado (JOINS)

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentado hacer una consulta en SqlServer, pero no me despliega el resultado deseado.

Tengo una tabla donde guardo licencias @TblLicencias y otra donde guardo en que equipo instale esas licencias @TblInstalacion, aumentando el correlativo si esa licencia ha pasado por varios equipos.

El problema que tengo es que quiero mostrar, un listado de todas las licencias existentes y al lado mostrar, el ultimo lugar donde fué instalada, y sino fue instalada que aparezca en blanco su record, solo mostrar la licencia.

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma, pero no logro que funcione.

```
declare  @TblLicencias table  (
        IdLicencia int,
        Licencia varchar(10)
)

declare @TblInstalacion table (
    IdInstalacion int,
    IdLicencia int,
    Correlativo int,
    Destino varchar(10)
)

insert into @TblLicencias (IdLicencia,Licencia)values(1,'ABDCEFGHIJ') --2 instalaciones
insert into @TblLicencias (IdLicencia,Licencia)values(2,'JHSDHEGHIJ') --nunca instalada
insert into @TblLicencias (IdLicencia,Licencia)values(3,'ABDYTEGHIJ') --1 instalación

insert into @TblInstalacion (IdInstalacion,IdLicencia,Correlativo,Destino)values(1,1,1,'OFICINA 1')
insert into @TblInstalacion (IdInstalacion,IdLicencia,Correlativo,Destino)values(2,1,2,'OFICINA 2')
insert into @TblInstalacion (IdInstalacion,IdLicencia,Correlativo,Destino)values(3,3,1,'SALA 1')

--SELECT *
--FROM @TblLicencias a
--LEFT JOIN @TblInstalacion b ON a.IdLicencia = b.IdLicencia
--WHERE a.IdLicencia IN (
--      SELECT MAX(Correlativo),IdLicencia
--      FROM @TblInstalacion
--      GROUP BY IdLicencia
--      )

--SELECT *
--FROM @TblLicencias a
--LEFT JOIN @TblInstalacion b ON a.IdLicencia = b.IdLicencia
--LEFT JOIN (
--      SELECT MAX(Correlativo) as Contador
--      FROM @TblInstalacion c   
--      GROUP BY IdLicencia
--      )c on b.Correlativo=c.Contador
```

El resultado correcto, debería ser así:

[image: Record]

Si alguien, puede ayudarme. Muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo, sería por medio de una subconsulta que entregue los máximos de `Correlativo` por cada `IdLicencia`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT  a.IdLicencia,
        c.Correlativo,
        c.Destino
        FROM @TblLicencias a
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   IdLicencia,
                MAX(Correlativo) AS MaxCorrelativo
            FROM @TblInstalacion
                        GROUP BY IdLicencia
        ) b 
             ON a.IdLicencia = b.IdLicencia
        LEFT JOIN @TblInstalacion c
             ON c.IdLicencia = a.IdLicencia
             AND c.Correlativo = b.MaxCorrelativo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho, muy agradecido.